# json callback returns id_str as number

Tags: twitter, coldfusion

I have searched everywhere on the web, I have twitter implementation with monkeh coldfusion. The thing is callback returns id_str as number instead of string and I can't use it to reply/retweet/follow.

Any idea why comes like that and what I have to change ?

Thank you

Comment: Without knowing more, it might be a problem with `serializeJSON()`, which has a number of issues maintaining data types. That said, we need more details. Please post the [*smallest* (stand-alone) example](http://www.sscce.org/) that reproduces the issue. *I have twitter implementation with monkeh coldfusion* Do you mean the http://monkehtweet.riaforge.org/ project?

Answer (score 0):

There may not be anything wrong with your code, `[id_str]` is a number. If you are looking for the text in the tweet, it can be found at `[text]`. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the we're using previous version of monkeh, once upgraded the id_str came as string.